# How to refactor recurrent ggplot settings?

Tags: r, ggplot2, refactoring

What is the best way to refactor those recurrent plot settings? I tried to write a function to return this stuff. It didn't work. What is the best way to do this in R?

Here is an example code:

```
ggplot(df.offer_stats.timeworks.accepted, aes(x=time_rate)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),color="black", fill="#009E73", alpha=.5, binwidth = 1) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(9,35,1)) +
geom_density(alpha=.3, fill="#009E73", adjust=2, trim = TRUE) +
ggtitle("Distribution of accepted timework offers") +
xlab("Stundenlohn (Verrechnung)") +
ylab("Verteilung") +
theme(
axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust = - 0.5),
axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, vjust = 1.5),
plot.title = element_text(size = 35, vjust = 1.5,face = "bold")
)
```

It should look like this :-):

```
ggplot(df.offer_stats.timeworks.accepted, aes(x=time_rate)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),color="black", fill="#009E73", alpha=.5, binwidth = 1) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(9,35,1)) +
geom_density(alpha=.3, fill="#009E73", adjust=2, trim = TRUE) +
plot_standard('title','xlab','ylab')
```

Comment: perhaps looking at the ggthemes https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/blob/master/R/fivethirtyeight.R package source will trigger some ideas

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution: :-)

```
plot_standard <- function(title, xlab, ylab){
return(
list(
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust = - 0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, vjust = 1.5),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 35, vjust = 1.5,face = "bold")
    ),
    ggtitle(title),
    xlab(xlab),
    ylab(ylab))
  )
```

}

Comment: nice! awesome package! :-)